# Specify Maximum Budget for CloudSQL

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a App which has a maximum daily budget of 0 USD. I have also stored a few items in Google Cloud Storage. Now, the thing is, I am charged because of Cloud Storage even though my max budget is set 0 USD. I am unsure about how I am getting billed. My question is, will the same thing happen if I start a cloudSQL instance ?

Are there any options to specify TOTAL app budget  ?

Is there a way to explicitly mention my maximum budget for cloudSQL ?

Currently, I am shown 'You are using the free quota' , but I am still charged for the storage

from the official website:

> Billing cycles
>
> When you enable billing you specify a maximum daily budget. This is
>   the maximum resource cost you are willing to pay. This daily budget
>   will limit the total amount you can be charged on any single day. The
>   daily budget should be large enough to be able to handle spikes in
>   resource usage. An application can only consume budgeted resources up
>   to its maximum daily budget. When an application exceeds its daily
>   budget, any operation whose free quota has been exhausted will fail.
>   Charges are posted in daily and monthly billing cycles:
>
> Daily: Every day you are charged for the resources you actually use.
>   Usage up to the free quota limits is included in the usage total, but
>   not in the billable amount. Usage above the free quota is charged at
>   the regular rates. Monthly: At the beginning of each month all daily
>   charges for the previous month are summed, applicable taxes are
>   computed, and the total charges are debited from the payment
>   instrument that is linked to the app.

But the maximum budgets for cloudSQL and storage are not mentioned

Comment: For the items you are storing in Google Cloud Storage, are they in the default bucket? It's probably called something like "app_id.appspot.com". The free tier for using cloud storage from App Engine only applies to the default bucket.

Comment: okay, and what about the cloudSQL ? is it possible to specify maximum budget for that ?

Comment: The maximum daily budget feature is specific to App Engine and is limited to that. Cloud SQL is not affected by the App Engine budget. Cloud SQL has no free usage tier, although if you have only one small instance, it's quite cheap. A single D0 instance could be about $1 or $2 per month: https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing#pricing-examples

Comment: I seem to have gotten something wrong. 
Why do I see this ?
Cloud SQL
remove edit D0 Instance
30.100 total days per month
0.1 GB, light I/O operations
$10.97
Monthly total: $10.97

Comment: It says around $10 , and you say its around $1-$2 per month.

Comment: The pricing is pretty clear: https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing. To have $2 per month you'd have to have around 80 hours of per use hours in the month.

Comment: suppose I connect to the database using mysqli_connect(), and not issue the mysqli_close(), will the instance be kept on indefinitely ?